# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 -- doesn't display compile error ID

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 SP1 doesn't display the compile error ID.

For example,

Error   1   ; expected  C:\temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  52  73  ConsoleApplication1

I expected to see some CSXXXX here. Where I can get it back?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Output Window (under View -> Output), you should see it there:

[image]